# Will tcpdump see packets that are being dropped by iptables?

Tags: firewall, iptables, tcp, tcpdump

I have a firewall with these simple rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1/32 --dport 6000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.16.20/32 --dport 6000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6000 -j REJECT
```

Now, suppose I am using **TCPDUMP** like this:

```
tcpdump port 6000
```

And I have host `192.168.16.21` trying to connect to port `6000`.

**Will/should `tcpdump` output some packets coming from `192.168.16.21`?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`tcpdump` uses `libpcap` and `libpcap` processes packets before they get processed by the firewall, so the answer is "yes".

Comment: This is only partially true. `tcpdump` will see inbound traffic before `iptables`, but will see outbound traffic only after the firewall has processed it. See https://superuser.com/q/925286/18898

Comment: so is there away to drop incoming packets from a specific IP so that even tcpdump won't even see them?

Comment: @23r23f23q The XDP API happens before the AF_PACKET API. Probable requires eBPF. See this schematic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg