# Why firewalld doesn't apply my drop rule?

Tags: linux, centos, security, firewall, redhat

In centos 7 I want to block traffic from a source IP (example 3.3.3.3) and for that I apply the following rule:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-source=3.3.3.0/24
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

After that command I checked that my rule applies by:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=drop
drop (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 3.3.3.0/24
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Here you can see the output of all the other active rules:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=public
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno4
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 5060/udp 16384-32768/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:

firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=internal
internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno1
  sources: 
  services: mdns dhcpv6-client samba-client ssh
  ports: 80/tcp 60024/tcp 5080/udp 8080/tcp 5060/tcp 161/udp 5080/tcp 5060/udp 16384-32768/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

In the route table the public zone is listed in that one which routes traffic for 3.3.3.0/24.

```
ip route
default via 1.1.1.1 dev eno4 
10.1.1.0/24 via 10.1.1.1 dev eno1
```

So that rule is applying, but I still get traffic (UDP) from this source IP on a listen Port (5060) on my centos machine. What is wrong with my rule?

**UPDATE**
as Michael mentioned there is an output of iptables -nvL

```
iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  46M   33G ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
53342 3122K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 315K   35M INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 315K   35M INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 315K   35M INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   85  3916 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
 1908 87293 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 46M packets, 21G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  46M   21G OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  eno4   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_internal  all  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_drop  all  --  *      *       3.3.3.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_drop  all  --  *      *       3.3.3.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      eno4    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_internal  all  --  *      eno1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_drop  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            3.3.3.0/24      
    0     0 FWDO_drop  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            3.3.3.0/24      

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_drop (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_drop_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_drop_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_drop_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_drop_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_drop_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_drop_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_internal (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_internal_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_internal_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_internal_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_internal_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_internal_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_internal_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_drop (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_drop_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_drop_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_drop_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_drop_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_drop_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_drop_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_internal (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_internal_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_internal_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_internal_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_internal_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_internal_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_internal_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 272K   32M IN_public  all  --  eno4   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
42964 2736K IN_internal  all  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 IN_drop    all  --  *      *       3.3.3.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_drop    all  --  *      *       3.3.3.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_drop (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 IN_drop_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_drop_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 IN_drop_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_drop_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_drop_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_drop_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_internal (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
42964 2736K IN_internal_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
42964 2736K IN_internal_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
42964 2736K IN_internal_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_internal_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353 ctstate NEW
  201 15678 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137 ctstate NEW
  627  144K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
  969 50388 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW
39727 2400K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:60024 ctstate NEW
    7  4458 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5080 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5060 ctstate NEW
 1252 90788 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:161 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5080 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5060 ctstate NEW
  140 28000 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpts:16384:32768 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_internal_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_internal_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 272K   32M IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 272K   32M IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 272K   32M IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5   196 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1184 70012 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
  388  271K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5060 ctstate NEW
 268K   31M ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpts:16384:32768 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       3.3.3.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       3.3.3.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

**UPDATE**
In the following ladder diagram (sngrep) you can see that the Option Ping (5060) is answered by my application so the firewall rule did not affect.

[image]

**UPDATE 2** 
The error occurs again, and now I reload the filter rule and the IP isn't apply to the drop list. I figure out that the issue occurs if the Interface has traffic load. After shutdown the server and restart the rule is applied. But I need a way to apply a drop rule also if the server has load.

Comment: The firewall looks right. Are you sure the IP address of the traffic is within that network? You seem to have used fake information, and we always recommend you [do not obfuscate](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) such things.

Comment: The traffic comes from eno4 interface but the drop zone do not have a interface, is this the issue? The eno4 interface is that one who get the traffic for 3.3.3.0/24

Comment: The interface is irrelevant when you set a source. That will always override a zone with an interface. Again, you should avoid obfuscating important information like IP addresses.

Comment: That was the sentence I realise also but the IP did not block anyway and I do not know why

Comment: @MichaelHampton: for not obfuscating my IP Address I create a new scenario with a different IP, but for that IP it works. So the issue is related to the original used IP Address. I try to revert all the firewall rules to zero and create that rule again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same/similar issues. After hours of troubleshooting, I have the following observations.

The order of the iptables rule chain (for 'public' zone) is:

```
IN_public_log 
IN_public_deny
IN_public_allow
```

Which means that 'deny' rules are processed before 'allow' rules - so this is significant in understanding what order the rules are matched. I don't know whether this order can be changed.

I came across the same issue in that issuing a `firewalld-cmd --reload` did not seem to impact whether the SIP packets gets dropped or accepted, but a reboot resolved it.

However, I found the `firewalld-cmd --complete-reload` command and that seems to be working better - although I think this will drop any existing sessions. But at least I can get the firewalld rules changed and not have to reboot to get it to fully/properly apply.

I have also noticed that sngrep still seem to be able to capture and display the SIP message even though it is blocked, but it shows it with a msg count of 1 and there is no response message (because it was actually blocked).

**UPDATE:** I understand sngrep (since 0.1.0) uses libpcap - see https://github.com/irontec/sngrep/wiki. According to this post libpcap process the (inbound) packets before they get process by the 'firewall'. I assume 'firewall' in this case can also mean firewalld. See [Will tcpdump see packets that are being dropped by iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/233302/will-tcpdump-see-packets-that-are-being-dropped-by-iptables)

Note: CentOS 7 seems to come with firewalld version 0.4.4.4. The latest is 0.6.0, but I don't know how to upgrade it yet. I'm hoping the newer versions may resolve/fix the above issues.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to get the rule working I create the block rule in two different ways. The first way was to put the IP in the drop zone with:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-source=3.3.3.0/24
```

and forget the reload command, so the rule didn't apply, next I create this entry to the firewall.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=3.3.3.0/24 reject'
```

And the I can't get the rule working with both entries in the firewall. After clear the firewall from all entries relating the 3.3.3.0/24 Network and recreate the rule with the drop zone it works for me.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing some fundamentals. 
There are interfaces, and interfaces belong to a zone (public by default). Rules for that zone are implemented on the all interfaces that belong to it.  You have two interfaces **eno1** (in zone **internal**) and **en4** (in zone **public**). As Nasir Riley suggested, you have to implement the rule on the zone where desired interface belongs. You are trying something to do with the zone "**drop**" but there is no interface in that zone. From Red Hat documentation for the **drop** zone:

> "Any incoming network packets are dropped; there is no reply. Only
>   outgoing network connections are possible."

So you could put desired interface to this zone, but first remove rule that you have added. 
And go thoroughly [RHEL 7 Security guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_firewalls), there are lot of information regarding firewalld .

Comment: In the documentation I can read that I do not need to apply a interface to that drop zone. Because the drop zone is applied to every interface that source IP comes in.

Comment: `You are trying something to do with the zone "drop" but there is no interface in that zone` - which is fine. A zone does not have to be bound to an interface in order to apply to some connection. Zones can be bound to source IP addresses only, like the `drop` zone exactly.