# Nginx: can reach a site via IP address but it doesn’t work with the domain name

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-22.04

I’ve started a nginx `webserver` recently with Ubuntu Server 22.04 as usual. The hypervisor is VMware Workstation 16.2.4. When I open the site `http://192.168.0.213` I can see the default nginx page. But if I try to use my domain name `example.com` page won’t be found… I make attempts on my host and on other virtual machines using `curl`. The result is the same. And I’m not able to open my site even from `webserver`! The command `nginx -t` output is successful.

```bash
obfuscateduser@dnsserver:~$ curl http://example.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused

obfuscateduser@webserver:~$ curl http://example.com
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 80 after 1 ms: Connection refused
```

**`/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`**

```bash
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

**`/var/www/example.com/html/index.html`**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to EXAMPLE.COM!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Success!  The your_domain server block is working!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Permissions**

```bash
obfuscateduser@webserver:~$ ll /var/www/example.com/html/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 obfuscateduser obfuscateduser 4096 Jan 12 12:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 11 17:19 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 obfuscateduser obfuscateduser  172 Jan 12 11:39 index.html
```

**Firewall output**

```bash
Status: active

To                      Action      From
--                      ------      ----
Nginx HTTP              ALLOW       Anywhere                 
OpenSSH                 ALLOW       Anywhere                 
Nginx HTTP (v6)         ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)            
OpenSSH (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Should I shut down the firewall? Or should I add a special entry in DNS zones files? Might I add some other records to the `example.com` file?

Comment: Is the DNS record for `example.com` actually pointing to the correct IP-address 192.168.0.213 ?

Comment: No, there's only an entry `webserver       IN      A       192.168.0.213` in the forward zone file. And `213     IN      PTR     webserver.example.com.` for the reverse zone.

Comment: Consider running curl with increased verbosity i.e. `curl -v curl http://example.com`  and for additional understanding and debugging https://serverfault.com/q/725262/984089 and https://serverfault.com/a/1109720/984089

Comment: @IlyaShmadchenko So you don't have a A record from `example.com` pointing to your webserver? If so, that's obviously why it doesn't work.

Comment: @diya, @vidarlo, I've added `example.com.        IN      A       192.168.0.213` to the `forward` zone. Now `curl` is working fine, I can see my site. Thank you! Should I add the same record to the `reverse` zone? Anyway, I'm going to check the `webserver`'s status tomorrow.

Comment: No need to use reverse zone to access the site!