# How can I check if an outgoing connection is blocked by local firewall?

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking, connection

I have a situation, where my server can't connect to an SMTP server, while my PC can. But the same server can connect to another SMTP server. I think that my firewall might be blocking it. How can I reliably test, if this issue caused by my firewall/iptables? Ideally, with   or each one alone.

There are many rules in the iptables and I may miss things. I was thinking of a tool, which would tell me if a e.g. outgoing connection to a host at port with TCP or UDP would be blocked or not.

PS: it is a Debian server and my laptop and the server are in different networks.

Comment: What OS are involved? Where are the different machines you mention (networkly speaking)? Do you have an actual physical firewall? What have you already tried? What was the result?

Comment: Are PC and server in the same or different subnets? Are other firewalls involved? What is the exact error message you encounter?

Comment: `How can I reliably test, if this issue caused by my firewall/iptables?` first step I would do is check the configuration of firewall/iptables

Comment: To check if the problem is the host based / local firewall on the server itself can be relatively easy : *"temporarily disable that firewall"* - To diagnose if the problem is another firewall (in your or your ISP's network for example) can be a bit more complex. When you get a "connection refused" error (from a friendly firewall rather than one that silently drops blocked packets) see: https://serverfault.com/q/1109623/37681

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant software firewall and I did not realize that there are different types in Linux systems ufw and firewalld.

Comment: `There are many rules in the iptables and I may miss things` just show your rules and we can tell you if they are a problem or not.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider but that's not the point. I would like to have a reliable method to test the rules without manually inspecting them. 1) Humans easily miss details in long list of entries. 2) I can't automate serverfault :)

Comment: Then learn how to read the output. Recommendations for tools are off topic here.

Comment: Well the problem is not to learn or I am not necessarily asking also for a tool (even though I used the term above), the problem is to have a simple method without going through each rule one by one.

Comment: Use the following command to test for an open TCP connection `nc -vz TARGET_IP TARGET_PORT`.

Comment: @paladin Thanks! I tried this but this does not tell me if the connection is blocked by my local firewall or by the firewall of the remote host.

Comment: Usually, if it's blocked by your local firewall, you will receive a reject signal, meaning the connection attempt will fail immediately. If it's blocked by the remote machine, you will receive a drop, meaning the connection attempt will fail after a drop timeout, often up to 60 seconds and more.

Comment: @paladin This is not true, I added a rule to block remote IP and it caused a time out after some time instead of failing immediately.

Comment: Because you used a `drop`, instead of a `reject`. For internal network, you should always use a `reject`, only for external networks, or public networks, a `drop` is a good choice.