# Postfix seems to be running and listening on the public network interface, but external clients cannot connect?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I'm setting up a new Postifx server on Debian 12. I've installed the Debian package and confirmed that Postfix is running, and is listening on ports `25`,`465`, and `587`.

Postfix is running and there are no errors in the log. I disabled the jails in `master.cf` and this server does not have a software firewall running.

Postifx is bound to all interfaces, per `netstat`:

```
netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8417/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8417/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8417/master
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      8417/master 
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      8417/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      8417/master
```

I can telnet on the server itself and connect to Postfix via it's public IP:

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 587
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix
```

But if I try this from outside the server, it won't connect:

```
telnet mydomain.com 587
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Trying xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

I have confirmed that DNS resolves correctly to the server from the client's perspective.

The ISP at my work/home does not block outgoing ports, as I can telnet to Gmail's SMTP server from home and get to `EHLO`.

The server hosting company claims that no ports are being blocked.

I can reach the server from my home client with `traceroute -I` but not without the `-I` option.

I honestly don't know what else to try. I should be getting something from Postfix when trying to telnet. Most of the options for blocking mail occur after the `EHLO`, and we haven't gotten that far.

What possible settings on the server would prevent Postifx from listening or responding on the external interface, when `netstat` shows that it is bound, there are no errors in the log, and Postfix responds to telnet on the server's external IP when telneting from the server itself?

`inet_interfaces = all` is set.
`inet_protocols = all` is set.

Are there any configuration settings that would cause Postfix to silently drop a connection request without any output at all?

What else can I check or try? Which settings in Postfix would drop or not accept an initial connection request?

Comment: I wrote a relative long debugging guide here https://serverfault.com/a/1109720/37681

Comment: And you tested with the IPv4 address while your telnet response `Trying xxxx:xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx...`. suggests that you also have at an IPv6 record

Comment: @HBruijn: The client tried both the IPv4 and IPv6 in order before timing out.

Comment: Check if you have firewall run on the machine and ports are permitted

Comment: @RomeoNinov There is no firewall software installed on the server at this time.

Comment: what kind of connection do we speak about, how is the device connecting? at the current stage is this question offtopic. Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. As also information about the research you have done

Comment: Use `tcpdump` to find out which host sends you an ICMP host unreachable packet in response to your `telnet` connection.

Comment: @AlexD: Telnet says, `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`. When I run `tcpdump -i any -nn dst xx.xx.xx.xx` I only see 14 packets going out before telnet times out. There doesn't seem to be any reply at all (blackhole).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone else: apparently there are many different firewalls besides `iptables` and `ucf`.

I found this helpful post: https://surgemail.com/knowledge-base/disable-your-firewall/, which lists all of the possibilities to look for. In my case, it was `nft`.

Here's the full list of firewalls to disable or check for:

```
nft flush ruleset
systemctl mask nftables.service

systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld

service iptables stop
service iptables disable

service ipchains disable
service ipchains stop

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

cfx -x
```